# Linq to SQL error SQL does not compare NText, Text, Xml, or Image?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

When trying to do an update for a Linq object I receive the following error.

> "SQL Server does not handle comparison of NText, Text, Xml, or Image
> data types."

There is a field in the database that is a Text field because it is going to hold a string that could be as much as 32kb.

Should I change the data type or is there a work around in Linq I could use?

EDIT

I have support SQL 2000 which is why it is a TEXT field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change it to a `VARCHAR(max)` - it will make life much easier.

---

EDIT

Full text indexing may help you here, not sure if SQL 2000 would allow you to then "search" on your text column

Comment: What about for SQL 2000 whcih I have to support?

Comment: What about if I can't change the type of the column? I'm still getting this exception even though UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never for the column in question (type NText). Any other solutions? It only occurs when updating data - if the field was null before the update then the code executes just fine. Thanks. David.

Comment: Full text indexing only allows use of the various fulltext predicates, `CONTAINS`, etc.  It is not possible in MSSQL 2k to compare these types of columns with `=`, `!=`, etc.

Answer (score 9):

you can always use ToString() on the string in question which will force client side comparison.

Comment: In my case I had an XML data type field and was able to resolve the error by changing the updateCheck attribute on the column in my model..[Column(Storage = "_CustomAttributes", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "xml", UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]

Answer (score 1):

You can manually change the Update Check to "Never" in the .dbml.

Comment: Please try to include relevant bits and be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set UpdateCheck in code:

```
        [Column(Name = "SomeXml", Storage = "_someXml", CanBeNull = true, UpdateCheck = UpdateCheck.Never)]
    public System.Xml.Linq.XDocument SomeXml { get { return _someXml; } set { _someXml = value; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change **ALL** the fields of the table to **NVARCHAR(MAX)** - Even the ones that you don't update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I just did something like this:

From this:

```
Dim query = From x In db.Transactions
            Where x.Description = "from ImnoX"
            Select x
```

to This:

```
Dim query = From x In db.Transactions
            Where x.Description.ToString = "from ImnoX"
            Select x
```